# Performance of data retrieval process from SQL views

Tags: sql, sql-view

**SQL** documentation states that

> The database engine recreates the data, using the view's SQL
>   statement, every time a user queries a **view**

How does data retrieval process from **SQL views** offers better performance as compared to execution of select query to retrieve data from tables.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the database you are using, the view you are using, etc.  You should label this question with a database vendor.

Comment: For a discussion of views in SQL Server and MySQL, you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302615/mysql-views-performance) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439056/is-a-view-faster-than-a-simple-query).

Comment: **It doesn't** - plain and simple. Views are **not** designed / intended to boost performance - they're intended to present a caller a more suitable / more flexible / more customized **view** of his data. They're great for reporting or for other purposees - but they are **NOT** performance improvements

Answer (score 0):

Basically **Views** are Used for Security purpose Than for performance,while Using Views you can restrict the users from Accessing a particular Table.

The only difference is Views can be saved and reused whenever required,than to rewrite the whole Query again.

Answer (score 0):

Views are just queries with names.
It is like saving a code snippet (in the database level) so you won't have to write the same code again and again.
Views have nothing to do with performance.

Being that said -
There is a mechanism named "**Materialized views**", where in this case the query result is actually stored in a table so it can be used without executing the query again and again.
The Materialized views results might be refreshed in multiple manners -
on demand, on schedule, every time the base table is being updated etc.